# how to add multiple hyperlinks and email links into an email signature made in adobe?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I made email signatures for a company in indesign.
i need to add hyperlinks for social media, website also clickalble links to the emailaddres and phone. Unless I would create the signature in mail, i dont know how to create hyperlinks.

I tried slicing everything up in photoshop and saving in html, it worked in the browser but as soon as i copied to mail; all images dissapeared just a bunch of blue questionmarks in boxes.

i saved as png /jpg images but then i can only add one link to the whole thing.. please help !!

Needless to say perhaps, but the signatures needs to work for all (or most) email clients like, outlook / gmail / mail etc

Thanks

Comment: For Outlook, signatures made in the mail client can only have 1 hyperlink. To make an html signature with hyperlinks (style sheets, animations, JavaScript not allowed) design your signature with an html editor using inline styles and minimize it.

Answer (score 0):

For Outlook, signatures made in the mail client can only have 1 hyperlink.

To make an html signature with hyperlinks (style sheets, animations, JavaScript not allowed) design your signature with an html editor using inline styles and minimize it.

Drop your signature.htm into this folder:

C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures

Images can reside in that folder, in a nested folder or on a separate web server, just make sure links reflect the location.

Now go into Outlook Signatures and select signature.htm (or whatever you named it .HTM).

Your signature may look funny in this preview. Select this signature for outgoing mail, start a new mail and send it to your self to test.